# How this configuration is done in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm a newbie learning flask. I found this following code in YouTube. He said he has configured the email USERNAME & PASSWORD in 'config.cfg'. Could anyone please tell me how this can be done. How to configure those values in 'config.cfg'?

[image: image source: YouTube]

Comment: For what you want to configure?

Comment: Loading vars from a config file is pretty old school.  I'd recommend using environment variables, as more modern hosting solutions support this method.  See a [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61679398/2052575) I wrote for more info on this.

Answer (score 1):

You should create `config.cfg` file. Inside this file, you should store all your configurations.

**config.cfg**

```
MAIL_USERNAME = 'your@mail.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD = 'YourPa$$w0rd'
```

If you any other configs you can add in the file like above and import it like below:

```py
app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg')
```

Comment: Just to add, the link to the documentation about [how handle configuration with Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#configuring-from-files).